# How to pass href value to template in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is the HTML.

```
<navlink v-bind:href="#about">About</navlink>
```

And the main.js code is

```
Vue.component('navlink', {
    template: '<li class="item"><a><slot></slot></a></li>'
});
```

But I'm getting error

> [Vue warn]: failed to compile template:
>   - invalid expression: v-bind:href="#about"

How to fix this?

Comment: I dont see any error [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k9v9rxma/). Have to included all relevant code.

Comment: @anoopchandran I am not sure at all if i intended this. very sorry for this mistake

Comment: @Muhammad Omar ElShourbagy .. Its Okay..Thank you

Comment: @saurabh..  I tried your code.. it doesnt work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I realise that you have solved this, but `v-bind` expects you to be pointing to an object in your parent class's `data` and you are trying to use a string literal, so Vue throws an error because it cannot find an object with that key.

You may also prefer to pass `href` as a prop to your component instead, so you end up with:

```
Vue.component('navlink', {
    template: '<li class="item"><a :href="href"><slot></slot></a></li>',
    props: ['href']
});
```

and then you can just do:

```
<navlink href="#about">About</navlink>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ov94tg5z/

Answer (score 1):

Try to add more quotes)

```
<navlink v-bind:href="'#about'">About</navlink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to fix it.. like this..
HTML

```
<navlink href="#about">About</navlink>
```

And JS

```
Vue.component('navlink', {
template: '<a class="item"><slot></slot></a>'
});
```

Comment: just my curiosity, href will be binded to a tag automatically? im new on vuejs btw.

Comment: seems like that.. I tried `Vue.component('navlink', {
    template: '<li class="item"><a><slot></slot></a></li>'
});` and the resulting HTML was `<li href="#about"><a class="item">About</a></li>`